# Difference between runtime and debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a very odd problem. I've written a little inhouse app which scrapes a load of URLs, performs HEAD requests to get the size and populate a ListView control. Everything works fine when I am running it inside Visual Studio when debugging, but when I deploy the listview does not populate. The 2 are making exactly the same calls consistently. Does anyone have any idea what may cause this to happen?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the visual studio debugger to your live program? (/Hadtoask)

Comment: How are you using VS2008 with .NET 4?

Comment: Sorry stupid moment.... I work with both IDEs, I'm obviously stuck in the past....

Comment: Ahhhh, sorry I is n00b.... Debug > Attach to process....

Comment: Try inserting a log just before you add a value to the Listview (and print the value in log) and just after adding (again print the value). Run in debug and live and compare the logs. It may point to something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I was able to find the solution by attaching the debugger to the process... many thanks to all for answering. I know this is a trivial question...

Many thanks

JT